# zip command in shell script doesn't work via crontab

Tags: linux, shell, cron, centos, zip

I have a simple shell script that copies a folder, zips it, then deletes the original folder.

```
#!/bin/bash

today=$(date +%m-%d-%Y)

cp -R /data /perf_backup/
/bin/zip -r data-"$today".zip data
rm -rf data
```

Works fine when I manually run it. The end result is a single zip file as expected.
[image]

However when cron job runs, only the initial data directory is there. As if everything after the initial folder copy is ignored.

[image]

Crontab is simply

```
* * * * 1-5 /opt/backup_data_folder.sh
```

This is on Oracle Linux Server 7.9 (ie CentOS)

Comment: I think you should specify absolute paths for `data-"$today".zip` and `data`, and please be careful with the `rm -rf` when you do this.

Comment: I think the problem is that for the manual execution you're actually in the directory `/perf_backup/` .... cron isn't.  Do a `cd /perf_backup/` after the `cp`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info . Good luck.

Comment: @Aeronautix thanks, the issue was relative vs absolute paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

today=$(date +%m-%d-%Y)

cd /perf_backup/
cp -R /data ./data_backup
zip -r data-"$today".zip data_backup
rm -rf data_backup
```